# matlab installation problem using the guidelines as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

Tags: matlab

While trying to install matlab following the guidelines as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB, I encountered a problem in the first step:

```
sudo: /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install: command not found
```

Kindly please help me sort this out because I need `matlab` urgently.

Comment: Where did you get matlab from? Where is it stored on your system? That command assumes that you have a CD containing matlab. Is that the case? Have you purchased matlab?

Comment: make the `install` file into an executable one. And also post the output of `ls -l /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A` command

Answer (score 0):

MAKE SURE that the instructions for installing MATLAB  are made specifically for your Ubuntu version. If not everything could go haywire or not work. Also make sure you have followed the steps to install the "ia32-libs" package from the link that says exactly that on the page.